# How to build an AutoEncoder / U-Net in Keras (tensorflow.keras) which used the Residual Skip Connections (ResNet Based Autoencoder)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I built and tested 2 different models which can give me `Bottleneck Features/Hidden Embeddings` but they did not give me very good results. My idea is to train a network which can find 'UseFul' Embeddings based on my task. The idea is to

1. Train an AutoEncoder / U-Net so that it can learn the useful representations by rebuilding the `Grayscale` Images (some % of total images. Say it is pre training task).
2. Strip the Embedding model only from that architecture and build a `Siamese` network based on top of that to further push the weights towards my task.
3. Get that trained `Siamese` network and extract embeddings from that network to get Similar Images in my vector space.

I used my 2 models but it starts overfitting, increasing the loss with increased layers. `ResNet` would stop that.

I would have used a simple pretrained model say `ReesNet` directly for the **3rd** point, but my images are grayscale and it is extracting extra information. I used `Grayscale` images and replicated itself 3 times to get a 3-channel image but still, it is of no use. I want to try this new model. Let us say below is the code for very simple [U-Net Xception-style model` architecture: from Keras Blog](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def get_model(img_size, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))

    ### [First half of the network: downsampling inputs] ###

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    # Blocks 1, 2, 3 are identical apart from the feature depth.
    for filters in [64, 128, 256]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    ### [Second half of the network: upsampling inputs] ###

    for filters in [256, 128, 64, 32]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(previous_block_activation)
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, padding="same")(residual)
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    # Add a per-pixel classification layer
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

I want to know how could I use `Resnet` architecture with this model? I can [build a Resnet Encoder](https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/resnet_keras/Residual_Networks_yourself.ipynb) model but Decoder, I am not able to get.

Comment: overfitting a model is a good thing. Dont change your architecture when your model overfits. instead heavily regularize it to reduce overfitting. Overfitting a model clearly suggests that your model is complex enough to model the problem at hand.

Comment: No but I check with `NasNet` and other to get the similarity score. The deeper a model goes, worse results it gives for top-5 results. Actually I have very unique problem at hand. Grayscale Images which has Text and Figures (diagrams, charts, graphs). I can't get similar images from text but training the model to search for these similar diagrams would improve it. That's why this unique task. If not, I'll just make something unique for the first time in my life. Both ways, its win win for me.